# How can i create a mongodb query that calculates the difference of a value along other timestamps using a unique id

Tags: mongodb

I have collected various data via the Twitch API and would now like to prepare and display it in a mondodb chart.
What I want to display are the viewer counts along the measurement points (timestamps). The IDs per timestamp should be compared with the viewer count. If the viewer count is equal to the previous timestamp, nothing should happen, if the value has changed, the difference to the current value should be entered e.g. in a new field. At the end I want to see on the x axis the timestamps and on the y axis the viewer count for the timestamps

here is a axample of the Object. Eevery minute I get one such object per active livestream (mostly 20 objects per request/timestamp)

```
_id:604672c85f68ef1c71546c71
 id:40931788941
user_id:493094533
game_name:"Science & Technology"
title:"Arduino Lasershow aus dem 3D-Drucker. #arduino #3D-Druck #CNC #Program..."
viewer_count:151
started_at:"2021-03-08T14:50:25Z"
language:"de"
time:2021-03-08T18:54:00.911+00:00
__v:0
```

most important attributes:

```
 id:40931788941
 time:2021-03-08T18:54:00.911+00:00
 viewer_count:151
```

My problem is that I don't know exactly how to calculate the difference to the previous object with native mongo. If you have another solution, bring it to me ;-)

EDIT:

You can see in the following screenshot the x axis the dates and on the y the viewer_count for this date. But the viewer_count is not meaningful because its a sum of all viewer_count values of all objects for the specific date.
I only want to get the cumulative value of the viewer_count attribute for the specific date.
Other aggregations for this attribute do not help much here either.
[image]

Comment: your question is not clear, just post 2/3 example documents and expected result from that docs.

Comment: @turivishal ok, sorry. i will do it. I know, it was not easy to explain

Comment: Maybe my added information helps here